# Merging multiple datasets together

Tags: sas

Hello I have a listing I'm struggling with as I don't think the code I am using is doing the job correctly. Here is the spec.

Dataset: Firstly, merge QS with SUPPQS by USUBJID, IDVARVAL= QSSEQ, keep only records where QSCAT=’SOFA’. Then merge with ADSOFA by USUBJID and QSSEQ. Only keep records where MITTFL=’Y’

and here is the code I'm using

```
proc sql;

create table qs (where=(qscat="SOFA" )) as

select a.*,b.qnam as SOFASCS,qval as avalc_qs from trans.qs as a

left join

trans.suppqs (where=(qnam='SOFASCS')) as b

on a.usubjid = b.usubjid and a.qsseq = input(b.idvarval,best.);

quit;



proc sort data=qs;

by usubjid qsseq;
run;



data adsofa;

set adb.adsofa;
run;



proc sort data=adsofa;

by usubjid qsseq;
run;



data qs01;

merge qs(in=a drop=studyid)
adsofa(in=b where=(mittfl = "Y"));

by usubjid qsseq;

if a or b;
```

I keep getting rows I don't want. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?.

Comment: Starting with one thing at a time, does your first query work correctly?
Can you include test data to highlight the issues, fake data is fine.

Comment: I will try to show fake data tomorrow. Thanks for your reply. I do think the proc sql isn't right but im not sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to convert your logic into a classical SQL.

```
proc sql;
  create table qs as
    select a.*
        ,b.qnam as SOFASCS
        ,qval as avalc_qs
    from trans.qs as a
    left join trans.suppqs as b
        on a.usubjid = b.usubjid and a.qsseq = input(b.idvarval,best.) and qnam='SOFASCS'
    where qscat="SOFA" ;
quit;

proc sql;
  create table qs01 as
    select qs.*, a.*
    from qs 
    full /* left? */ join adb.adsofa as a
        on a.usubjid = qs.usubjid and a.qsseq = qs.qsseq and mittfl = "Y"
  ;
quit;
```

I assume that you did not really want to have a full join but a simple left loin in the last one.